# How to find reason a TextBox has lost focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple form with a `TextBox` and 2 buttons. One of the buttons has been designated as the form's `CancelButton`.

The `TextBox` has a `Validating` event procedure which is called when either button is clicked (or the `TextBox` loses focus for any other reason).

When the `Validating` event procedure is entered how can I detect that the `CancelButton` has been clicked?

Comment: *"which is called when either Button is clicked (or the Textbox loses focus for any other reason)"* - How is it being called?  Can you pass a value to it which would indicate this information?

Comment: I think you might have to get your cancel button to set a member flag to indicate it was clicked (for you to test in your validating) - as far as I can see / test, `_Leave()` and `_LostFocus()` both fail to provide the control that gained the focus as the corresponding WM_KILLFOCUS would give.

Comment: The Textbox.Validating event procedure is called before the first event procedure associated with the 'Cancel' button. Therefore there is nothing the code associated with the Cancel button can do to indicate it has been clicked. It seems odd to me that .Net does not have a mechanism to indicate why a control has been left/lost focus.

Comment: Is your eventual aim clicking the Cancel button *without running* the Validating event handler? If this is the case then you can achieve this with `btnCancel.CausesValidation = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mustafa, your suggestion was exactly what I was looking for.

By setting the 'CausesValidation' property of my 'Cancel' button to 'false', the Validating event for textbox the never fires when the Cancel button is clicked.

Problem solved.